# Changing date time of server stops Execution of SSIS package, How to test time dependency?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Changing date time of server stops Execution of SSIS package, How to test time dependency? (Error at the bottom)

I have an SSIS package that uses 3 servers,

1.Server A to get data from

2.Server B to insert data into

3.Server C is where the SSIS package lives and gets executed from.

I have a select logic depending on GetDate() when getting data from server A,

For testing, Changing date on Server C to activate the logic depending on GetDate() does not apply the expected logic.

Changing the Date on all 3 servers or just server A and C, or just C causes error : "Description: Unable to load the package as XML because of package does not have a valid XML format. A specific XML parser error will be posted."

The same SSIS package runs as expected when changing the date on dev machine as all 3 database reside on the same server on the dev machine.

Why the hell loading of XML depends on what date it is??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

messing with system date & time may put you into trouble difficult to debug (as you already discovered).

remove the dependency on `GETDATE()` replacing it with a variable/parameter; when running in production that parameter will be filled by a `GETDATE()` but when testing you can replace it with a value of your choice.